# Grails findAll() fails, but only some times

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So, I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out. We have three domain tables: Product, Group, ProdGroupState. ProdGroupState looks like this,

```
Class ProdGroupState{
    Product product
    Group group
    State state
    String indicator
}
```

We have a new page which lets users generate reports, including listing the ProdGroupState indicator for all States for a given Product/Group pair. The code that generates the list is

```
def prodGroupStateInstance = ProdGroupState.withCriteria{
    and{
        eq "group", groupInstance
        eq "product", productInstance
     }
}
```

On each page of the report we call the same method that has that code, passing it a different product each time. Testing locally shows everything fine, and the correct data is in the report.

The issue we have is that once we moved the code from our local machines to our test server (Websphere if it matters), the code above is no longer pulling in the correct data. But it does it very inconsistently. Only one of the Products is having issues, the others all get the correct data. The one that isn't working ends up with `prodGroupStateInstance` being `[]` for all but one Group used. That Group has the expected values: [Y, Y, Y, N, ...] for all 50 States

Checking the logs for debug statements shows that `groupInstance` and `productInstance` have the expected values, and if the problem was the `withCriteria` call then you'd expect it to occur for every Product. So I'm more or less stumped why something that was tested locally on multiple machines and was working fine would fail in such a bizarre way after being deployed.

Comment: Is the `datasource` same when run locally against when run in WAS? If they are different then, try to use the datasource, that is configured in WAS, locally and see if you are able to replicate the issue locally.

Comment: WAS hits a different schema than local, but they are mirrors of each other and have the same data. I will try changing the local to hit the same schema as WAS, hadn't thought of that before